# pthread_rwlock functions missing in libc of ndk?

Tags: pthreads, android-ndk

I am trying to port some c++ code to my android application using NDK.
But the c++ code involves calls to some pthread_rwlock functions which is absent in the libc provided with the NDK.

I have found implementations of these functions but including them, it asks for more header files and more implementations and the problem grows.

Does somebody have a solution to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled over the same issue with NDK r5b where rwlock was in the header but not in the lib.
In the latest r5c this seems resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Android's pthread implementation lacks read/write locks. You'll need to use standard locks instead. A work around may be to write some wrappers that simply use the standard locks. Another approach may be to use Android's atomic APIs to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant items in the AOSP bug database:

- [pthread_rwlock functions are missing](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12369)
- [pthread_rwlock static init constant is broken](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15306)